# Tightly coupled controllers architecture

Tags: angularjs

Getting started with Angular, I am trying to implement a toolbar.

The application is structured in a menu bar, a view and the toolbar that form the web-page.

This toolbar has a general purpose (provides help functionality and error display), but for specific views adds some buttons that control the functionality (save, cancel, edit, delete, etc).

In the current design the view and the toolbar are siblings. The view controller depends on the data the view contains, and it can have different functionality. (For example: A view might allow data import, so there will be an import function in the toolbar, while other view might not.)

My problem is I cannot picture the structure of the communication between the view and the toolbar. Because the controllers are tightly coupled a service does not seem to address the communication.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- Share data between different controllers/services using rootScope
  (use wisely)
- You can Publish and Subscribe for app events using
  `$on`, `$broadcast` and `$emit`

One good strategy which I have used and helped is to keep all App events definition in one service called something like AppEvents so you can easily keep track of them and control what event causes what from a single place.

[Here is one nice article to read that expands more on this topic](http://mariuszprzydatek.com/2013/12/28/sharing-data-between-controllers-in-angularjs-pubsub-event-bus-example/)

Comment: I like the part with keeping the events in a service. I was examining now another way which is similar. Having a service with some variables. Then watching those variables on both the view and the toolbar. Would that work?

Comment: Yes, their controller can listen to events as they all have the events service injected and can use it